# CakePHP Shell weirdness: working directory mangled and can't find shells

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been running into an issue with running CakePHP 1.3 shells.  I have a shell that I want to test, so I change to the directory of my app and attempt to run it:

```
$ pwd
/path/to/cakephp/app
$ ../cake/console/cake
No configuration could be loaded for domain /path/to/cakephp/app. Exiting...
```

Okay, that's a little weird.  So let's try to pass an -app to it:

```
$ ../cake/console/cake -app /path/to/cakephp/app

Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.8 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:
 -app: /path/to/cakephp/app/
 -working: /path/to/cakephp//path/to/cakephp/app
 -root: /path/to/cakephp
 -core: /path/to/cakephp
```

...huh?  The core dir is completely wrong and I have no idea what's going on with that working directory.  Passing a working directory with `-working` results in the exact same output.

On top of that, none of my shells are being detected.  I notice in the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1106/The-CakePHP-Console) that this command is supposed to show a list of directories where it is looking for shells and tells you if there are none with `- none`.  Instead, no directories show up, period.  The shells are in `app/vendors/shells` for what it's worth.

So...I'm lost.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by someone on Cake's core team:

```
13:10:15 <savant> AlexMax: 1.3.8 has known issues with shells
13:10:19 <savant> please update to 1.3.13
```

Well, guess that sorts it.